# Laravel 429 erron on /oauth/token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

Like in the title. Everytime when I try to connect to my api server I get 429 error. I have commented out throttle from Kernel.php

Comment: Does this help? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/oauthtoken-resulted-in-a-429-too-many-requests

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to comment the throttle. Instead try to find what is the reason for 492. I suggest you use a request logging package and find the requests going to the server. Mostly the issue has to be unintended requests going to server or same request going over and over.

you can use this package and have a log of requests.
https://github.com/aungwinthant/apilogger